# Incomplete page load in Ruby On Rails

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, mongodb

I'm fairly new to Ruby on Rails so I'm not sure what to search for because I'm just not finding the answers I need to the problem.

I have several pages in a web app and after a few clicks in my development environment, some pages just stop loading data without any errors in the console or firebug. Looking at the HTML generated, it doesn't cut off the code in any consistent fashion... sometimes it'll cut off in the middle of writing an element's properties. It happens in Firefox and Chrome.

I've spent the last 3 or 4 days moving a lot of logic out of the .erb pages and into controllers and helpers and presenters, and triple checking missing HTML tags, missing javascript semi-colons... but still it persists. I haven't encountered this on our test and production sites, but seeing it in the development environment concerns me.

Anyone have any idea where a good place to look would be?

My code is all in an intranet machine, and there is a lot of it, so I'm not sure what kind of code to post. The data that fails to load is coming from a mongoDB and we're putting it lists and tables, and both are victims of the fail.

Comment: Did you check your Rails logs (*e.g.*, `log/development.log`)?

Comment: Yeah, I tail it while I'm in dev and often refer to it. There are no errors there.

Comment: I have never seen or heard anything like this before in my 4+ years of doing Rails dev. Share with us your OS/Ruby/Rails version info and the development logs. Do you use Webrick for running the app?

Comment: In Rails you can run in production, development, or test. If your failing case is one of these and success case is another, then you'll need to examine what's different and focus on that. For example, what gems are loaded, etc.

Comment: Is this random (or seemingly random)?  That is, can you just refresh a page repeatedly and get different html each time?

Comment: It is completely random. There are no errors anywhere... like it just times out and says "here's what you can have, i'm done". I can click a link, get 20 results, click the same link and get 23 results, then click it again and get all 30. (this is just a random example). the issue is that anything below the HTML that is output doesn't display or fire (such as any inline scripts).

Comment: Can you give an example of an .erb that has this happen? Also the view source on a page that didn't load properly.

Comment: It happens on several pages, randomly. It'll cut off sometimes just in the middle of writing and element:
`<a href="link_to_something_somewh`

Comment: Hmm then what lurker suggested is probably the best way to find it, look at your gemfile for things like `group :development do`, and in `config/environments/development.rb` compared to `config/environments/production.rb` and start isolating differences. Other things you can try are looking at the response in your browser (network tab in chrome, select the actual html page). Additionally, add `after_filter do    puts response.body    end` to your controller, this will show everything that rails sent to the browser.

Comment: Looks to me more like os/memory/network bugs, try to isolate the problem, run it on another machine, look at the system logs, try to write simple test to get a guaranteed failure and disable everything gradually until it will pass... try another rails app and look for similar behavior.

Comment: @Clark: looks like you might be on to something... my gemfile has a :development block and after process of elimination, `gem 'thin'` seems to be causing some sort of issue. (not using it causes other issues, but it's a great start). if you make it an answer, i'll accept it as such....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per the comments, and Lurker's suggestion of searching for development specific configurations.

`group :development do` in the gemfile and differences between `config/environments/development.rb` and `config/environments/production.rb` are a good start to help isolate problems specific to the development environment.

Comment: After a process of elimination, the gemfile was using the 'thin' gem in dev and this was causing the issues that I was having. Defaulting to Webrick helped fix the loading issue, but we were using Thin to allow longer URIs in queries. The production enviro is using apache, so this issue doesn't exist there. At least I know where to look now, thanks!

Comment: This isn't an answer. What was the actual problem? Any idea what "thin" was doing (and consequently why removing it helped)?